# Changing Leaflet map tooltip language

Tags: leaflet, tooltip

How do we change the language of leaflet? Not the map, the tooltip of zoom buttons, draw buttons, drawpolygon, cancel etc.

Comment: Do you mean Leaflet or the Leaflet.draw plugin? Check this comment in the code: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/73cd238820cc11c12af88c8c84a251d4d5ac3dad/src/Leaflet.draw.js#L59

Comment: Both. In leaflet also there is zoom in zoom out etc. And also in leaflet.draw plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Leaflet.draw uses the L.drawLocal configuration object to set any text used in the plugin. Customizing this will allow support for changing the text or supporting another language.

For more detail see [Leaflet.draw.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/src/Leaflet.draw.js), actually, you can find default strings there but I've provided an example here for you to check how it gonna work.

E.g.

```
   // Set the button title text for the polygon button
    L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.polygon = 'Draw a sexy polygon!';
    
    // Set the tooltip start text for the rectangle
    L.drawLocal.draw.handlers.rectangle.tooltip.start = 'Not telling...';
```

Till now you learned how this package works but I brought an example of what I've done before for you, So below I changed leaflet tools language to Persian

```
  L.drawLocal = { 
      draw: {
        toolbar: {
          // #TODO: this should be reorganized where actions are nested in actions
          // ex: actions.undo  or actions.cancel
          actions: {
            title: 'لغو ترسیم ',
            text: 'لغو'
          },
          finish: {
            title: 'اتمام ترسیم',
            text: 'اتمام'
          },
          undo: {
            title: 'حذف آخرین نقطه ی ترسم  شده',
            text: 'حذف اخرین نقطه'
          },
          buttons: {
            polyline: 'رسم چند خطی',
            polygon: 'رسم چندضلعی',
            rectangle: 'رسم مستطیل',
            circle: 'رسم دایره',
            marker: 'رسم نشان گذار',
            circlemarker: 'رسم نشانگر دایره ای'
          }
        },
        handlers: {
          circle: {
            tooltip: {
              start: 'جهت  رسم دایره کلیک کنید و بکشید'
            },
            radius: 'شعاع'
          },
          circlemarker: {
            tooltip: {
              start: 'جهت قراردادن دایره روی نقشه کلیک کنید.'
            }
          },
          marker: {
            tooltip: {
              start: 'جهت قراردادن نشانگر روی نقشه کلیک کنید'
            }
          },
          polygon: {
            tooltip: {
              start: 'جهت رسم شکل کلیک کنید',
              cont: 'جهت ادامه ترسیم شکل کلیک کنید',
              end: 'نقطه ی ابتدایی را جهت بسته شدن شکل کلیک کنید'
            }
          },
          polyline: {
            error: '<strong>Error:</strong> shape edges cannot cross!',
            tooltip: {
              start: 'جهت رسم خط کلیک کنید',
              cont: 'جهت ادامه ترسیم خط کلیک کنید',
              end: 'نقطه ی ابتدایی را جهت اتمام خط کلیک کنید'
            }
          },
          rectangle: {
            tooltip: {
              start: 'جهت ترسیم مستطیل کلیک و درگ کنید'
            }
          },
          simpleshape: {
            tooltip: {
              end: 'جهت اتمام ترسیم موس را رها کنید'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      edit: {
        toolbar: {
          actions: {
            save: {
              title: 'ذخیره ی تغییرات',
              text: 'ذخیره'
            },
            cancel: {
              title: 'لغو ویرایش، نادیده گرفتن تغییرات قبلی',
              text: 'لغو'
            },
            clearAll: {
              title: 'پاک کردن تمامی لایه ها',
              text: 'پاک کردن'
            }
          },
          buttons: {
            edit: 'ویرایش لایه ها',
            editDisabled: 'هیچ لایه ای جهت ویرایش وجود ندارد',
            remove: 'حذف لایه ها',
            removeDisabled: 'هیچ لایه ای جهت حذف وجود ندارد'
          }
        },
        handlers: {
          edit: {
            tooltip: {
              text: 'Drag handles, or marker to edit feature.',
              subtext: 'جهت نادیده درنظرگفتن تغییرات دکمه لغو  را کلیک کنید'
            }
          },
          remove: {
            tooltip: {
              text: 'جهت پاک شدن فیچر روی آن کلیک کنید'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: I know it has been two years but I just want to point out for those who will be looking at this answer that it's worth noting that customizing the options like "L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.polygon = 'Draw a sexy polygon!';" has to be called before the plugin instance is initialized.